# keep all connected clients' ip in netty

Tags: sockets, netty

My TCP server uses netty.The situation is: When a client connects to the server,I will save the client's ip in a global variable(such as a Map); When the client is disconnected,I will remove the IP from the map.

I used channelConnected() and channelDisconnected() method in SimpleChannelHandler.But my problem is ,some times the channelDisconnected() method cannot catch the event when I think the client is disconnected(maybe the computer closed,or the client process closed,or some other situations...) Can you give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Just use DefaultChannelGroup which will automatically remove the Channel from it when it was closed.

Alternative you can register a ChannelFutureListener to the Channels close future to do the removal from your map. 
Something like this:

```
channel.getCloseFuture().addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
    public void operationCompleted(ChannelFuture f) {
        map.remove(f.getChannel());
    }
});
```